# Binding redirect not redirecting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json.net

I've run into an issue where I'm getting an error about something trying to load an old version of a dll that is no longer even on the machine.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I already had a redirect in the webconfig to deal with this:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="NewtonSoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

There are no references to the 6.0.0.0 build in the solution. A dependency perhaps? If so I have no idea how to get the run time to tell me who the guilty part is.

Why is this still faulting?

Comment: Azure SDK is the one I run in to the most frequently that has a dep on 6.0.0.0.

Comment: @vcsjones We aren't using Azure at all.

Comment: Do you have another project that maybe use that version of Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: @ybrajim Not that I can tell, is there a way to get the runtime to tell me which dependency is causing it to try and load the wrong version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the answer was right in front of me. The assemblyBinding tag has an appliesTo attribute that specifies which versions should be redirected per .Net framework version.

```
assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727"
```

For some reason it was set to v2.0 - the application is running v4.0 so the redirects where not applying. Removing the attribute corrects the issue.

```xml
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="NewtonSoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: This is such a frustratingly easy fix. I was originally getting the issue with Newtonsoft.Json, but added a new package that inserted a new redirect; then that new redirect was the one having the issue. That tipped me off to the fact that it wasn't just NewtonSoft that wasn't redirecting, it was _all_ bindings